# Android Jetpack Navigation - Notify Bottom Nav View of Correct Item

Tags: android, navigation, bottomnavigationview, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm running into an issue where the navigation UI doesn't select the correct bottom navigation view item WHEN DEEP LINKING to a 2nd level fragment.

Here's what I mean:

- select **fragment_reading_lists**: correct bottom nav item is selected
- navigate from **fragment_reading_lists** -> **fragment_discover_landing**: correct bottom nav item is
  selected
- deep link to **fragment_reading_lists**: correct bottom nav item is selected
- !!deep link to **fragment_discover_landing**: correct bottom nav item is NOT selected!!

What happens when I deep link to fragment_discover_landing?  The default bottom nav item is selected.

Is there a way to notify the bottom nav adapter of which item SHOULD be selected in this instance?

Here's my nav graph:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragment_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_home"
        android:name="com.my.app.fragments.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/nav_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/home_fragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragment_home_to_fragment_browse_categories"
            app:destination="@id/fragment_browse_categories" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_browse_categories"
        android:name="com.my.app.fragments.BrowseCategoriesFragment"
        android:label="@string/discover_default_header"
        tools:layout="@layout/browse_categories_fragment" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_reading_lists"
        android:name="com.my.app.fragments.ReadingListHubFragment"
        android:label="@string/nav_readinglists"
        tools:layout="@layout/readinglists_landing">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragment_reading_lists_to_fragment_discover_landing"
            app:destination="@id/fragment_discover_landing" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_browse_library"
        android:name="com.my.app.fragments.BrowseLibraryFragment"
        android:label="@string/nav_library"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_mylibrary_all" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_downloads"
        android:name="com.my.app.fragments.DownloadsFragment"
        android:label="@string/nav_downloads"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_mylibrary_offline" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_discover_landing"
        android:name="com.my.app.fragments.DiscoverLandingFragment"
        android:label="@string/nav_discover_landing"
        tools:layout="@layout/discover_landing_fragment">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/fragment_discover_landing_back_action"
            app:popUpTo="@id/fragment_reading_lists"
            app:popUpToInclusive="false" />
        <argument
            android:name="category"
            android:defaultValue="Latest"
            app:argType="string" />
        <argument
            android:name="searchText"
            app:argType="string" />
        <argument
            android:name="searchMode"
            android:defaultValue="false"
            app:argType="boolean" />
        <deepLink
            android:id="@+id/discover_landing_category"
            app:uri="myApp://discover/category?name={category}" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

SIDE NOTE:  Neither of these fragments is the start destination.  That is the home fragment, which is item1 in the bottom nav.  fragment_reading_lists is the first fragment for item2 in the bottom nav

Comment: Can you include your navigation graph? Which of these fragments is your `startDestination`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake will do.  neither.  startDestination is... let's call it fragA (bottom nav item position 1.  frag1 in the op is bottom nav item position 2)

Comment: @ianhanniballake updated OP with nav graph

Comment: Can you replace `frag1` and `frag2` with the actual names from your navigation graph?

Comment: @ianhanniballake done

Answer (score 0):

As per the [deep link documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link):

> When a user opens your app via an explicit deep link, the task back stack is cleared and replaced with the deep link destination. When [nesting graphs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-nested-graphs), the start destination from each level of nesting—that is, the start destination from each  element in the hierarchy—is also added to the stack.

Therefore when you deep link to `fragment_discover_landing`, the back stack is `mobile_navigation`, `fragment_home`, then `fragment_discover_landing`. Since `fragment_reading_lists` is not a `startDestination` of a graph, it isn't added to the back stack and hence, the `OnDestinationChangedListener` that `setupWithNavController` uses to select the appropriate tab never sees that destination.

If you want `fragment_reading_lists` to be on your back stack, it needs to be the startDestination of a nested graph that contains your `fragment_discover_landing` destination:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragment_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_home"
        android:name="com.my.app.fragments.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/nav_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/home_fragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragment_home_to_fragment_browse_categories"
            app:destination="@id/fragment_browse_categories" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_browse_categories"
        android:name="com.my.app.fragments.BrowseCategoriesFragment"
        android:label="@string/discover_default_header"
        tools:layout="@layout/browse_categories_fragment" />

    <!-- Make sure to change your menu.xml to use @+id/reading_lists -->
    <navigation
        android:id="@+id/reading_lists"
        app:startDestination="@+id/fragment_reading_lists">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_reading_lists"
            android:name="com.my.app.fragments.ReadingListHubFragment"
            android:label="@string/nav_readinglists"
            tools:layout="@layout/readinglists_landing">
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_fragment_reading_lists_to_fragment_discover_landing"
                app:destination="@id/fragment_discover_landing" />
        </fragment>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_discover_landing"
            android:name="com.my.app.fragments.DiscoverLandingFragment"
            android:label="@string/nav_discover_landing"
            tools:layout="@layout/discover_landing_fragment">

            <action
                android:id="@+id/fragment_discover_landing_back_action"
                app:popUpTo="@id/fragment_reading_lists"
                app:popUpToInclusive="false" />
            <argument
                android:name="category"
                android:defaultValue="Latest"
                app:argType="string" />
            <argument
                android:name="searchText"
                app:argType="string" />
            <argument
                android:name="searchMode"
                android:defaultValue="false"
                app:argType="boolean" />
            <deepLink
                android:id="@+id/discover_landing_category"
                app:uri="myApp://discover/category?name={category}" />
        </fragment>

    </navigation>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_browse_library"
        android:name="com.my.app.fragments.BrowseLibraryFragment"
        android:label="@string/nav_library"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_mylibrary_all" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_downloads"
        android:name="com.my.app.fragments.DownloadsFragment"
        android:label="@string/nav_downloads"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_mylibrary_offline" />
</navigation>
```

Note that per the [Design navigation graphs documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-design-graph):

> [nested graphs] also provide a level of encapsulation — destinations outside of the nested graph do not have direct access to any of the destinations within the nested graph.

So this would have a side effect of making it so that your `fragment_discover_landing` would not be visible to any destination outside of `fragment_reading_lists`. [This issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110412864) tracks navigating via a deep link, which would allow you to access the destination from anywhere in your app via the URL deep link you've attached to it, but it is not yet available.